# How to add jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut to mouse event functions?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am using jQuery to change images on a mouse events (hover), but I can't figure out the best way to add a `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to fire for the following function.

```
        var sourceIn = function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
            $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
            $this.attr('src', newSource);
        }
        var sourceOut = function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
            $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
            $this.attr('src', newSource);
        }

        $(function () {
            $('img.toggle').mouseenter(sourceIn);
            $('img.toggle').mouseleave(sourceOut);
        });
```

I have  tried numerous ways to append `fadeToggle` to the above and I'm not sure what the best technique is.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hn5w7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just change the `src`, use the callback from `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`

```
$this.fadeOut(function() {
    $this.attr('src', newSource).fadeIn();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hn5w7/1/